# What is the easy way to package my python program as desktop application?

Tags: python, windows, package

How could I turn my python program to a windows application? 
As python is a scripting language how we make its programs for desktop applications

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python in Desktop Application Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8848285/python-in-desktop-application-development)

Comment: If I understand the above link is an IDE for developing Python programs.  OP wants to know how to turn his completed program into an executable to be installed and run on a desktop PC.  Hence, I don't think that is the correct duplicate link.

Comment: If your using Python 3 I suggest CxFreeze

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to use [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Go to your program’s directory and run:

```
pyinstaller yourprogram.py
```

This will generate the bundle in a subdirectory called dist.